# directory is not creating while running bash shell script in php

Tags: php

i want to execute a bash shell script in `php`. The shell script used to create make a directory. But it is not creating while i am running the `.php` file in server.

The php code for above i have used-------

```
<html>
<?php
echo exec('./home/biswajit/lh.sh')
?>
thanx
</html>
```

And the code for corresponding `lh.sh` file is------

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF | /home/biswajit/matlab  -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay /> /home/biswajit/matlab_result.out
mkdir('/home/biswajit/Done');
disp('directory created');
exit
EOF
```

Comment: `mkdir('/home/biswajit/Done');` is a bash command? I think it should be `mkdir -p /home/biswajit/Done`

Comment: sorry,But this is not command this matlab command.

Answer (score 0):

Check with which user's permissions it's run.  You could echo the output of "whoami" (bash) command to know with wich user is used to run the script.

If it's executed, for example, with the "www-data" user (ubuntu's [and maybe others] default httpd user), then it may not have the rights to create a directory in your user's home folder.

Comment: yes this the case.Then what i can do to run the shell script.

Comment: 2 possibilites here: 
(safe one) create a directory specifically for this task and change the group ownership (with the chgrp command) and permissions so the httpd can write to it.  For example if you want the script to be able to create files and directories in /home/biswajit/MatLabOutput, then create a MatLabOutput, "chgrp www-data MatLabOutput" and then "chmod 770 MatLabOutput" so the httpd service user's group can write to it.  
(unsafe one) use suEXEC to grant your user's privileges to the httpd service.

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as root if requested), it solves the limitations of exec() and shell_exec(). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('cat <<EOF | /home/biswajit/matlab  -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay /> /home/biswajit/matlab_result.out');
$return2  = $shell->exeCmd('mkdir -p \'/home/biswajit/Done\'');

//the return will be a string containing the return of the command
echo $return1;
echo $return2;
```